# .verify command not giving role (discord.py 1.7.3)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot, and with this bot I want to create a verify command. I started working on it, and everything works to the point of giving the reaction (Sending message with the "yes and "no" reactions), when I run the code, it doesn't throw any errors. If you do help me, I would please also like an explanation of why my code doesn't work and why your's does if you can, so I can learn.
Thank you! -JJ

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
  verifier = ctx.author
  jj = await client.fetch_user(270397954773352469)
  validReactions = ['✅', '']
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified")
  await ctx.send(f'{verifier}... Awaiting Verification, you will recieve a dm when you are verified')
  dm = await jj.send(f'{verifier.mention} is trying to be verified, do you know him/her?')
  await dm.add_reaction("✅")
  await dm.add_reaction("")

  def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in validReactions
  reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=float('inf') , check=check) #float('inf') for no timeout on when I can add the reaction for yes or no

  if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
    await verifier.send("You have been verified")
    await client.add_roles(verifier, role)
  elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
    await verifier.send("You have not been verified, please try again if you think this was a mistake, or contact the owner")
```

Answer (score 0):

You send a message to person called `jj` and `user == ctx.author` in `check` function is always True. (Because `ctx.author` can not see that message). So, try to replace

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in validReactions
```

with

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == jj and str(reaction.emoji) in validReactions
```